prisma client failing with vercel, despite the official solution being implemented
I'm getting this error in my next.js project deployed on vercel.
PrismaClientInitializationError: Prisma has detected that this project was built on Vercel, which caches dependencies. This leads to an outdated Prisma Client because Prisma's auto-generation isn't triggered. To fix this, make sure to run the `prisma generate` command during the build process.
Learn how: https://pris.ly/d/vercel-build
    at pa (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:33:69)
    at new r (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:3083)
    at 2618 (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.js:1:2114)
    at t (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at a (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.js:1:732727)
    at /vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.js:1:732758
    at t.X (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1206)
    at /vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.js:1:732740
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/notes_demo/.next/server/app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.js:1:732785)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14) {
  clientVersion: '5.12.1',
  errorCode: undefined
}
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/webhooks/clerk
    at /vercel/path0/notes_demo/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1258:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "prisma generate && next build" exited with 1

The problem is that i've followed the exact steps provided in the solution link referenced in the error.
Earlier in the logs i can see that the prisma client was succesfully created but for some reason vercel is trying again.
My package.json 'scripts' is below
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },

I've tried all the other permutations of the solution, including overriding the build commands in vercels settings.

problem was importing the prisma client from the official package rather than the generated folder.
Solve:
import { PrismaClient } from '@/generated/prisma-client'

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient()
}

declare global {
  var prismaGlobal: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>
}

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton()

export default prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma


If you're using app folder structure import PrismaClient like this or else it will give you "cannot find './generated/client' module error
"use client";

import { PrismaClient } from "@/src/app/generated/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
    return new PrismaClient();
};

declare global {
    var prismaGlobal: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
}

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma;

export const db = prisma;

//this is your schema.prisma file inside prisma folder down below
generator client {

provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output = "/src/app/generated/client"

}

